# About Camera Integration with website Idea

Tags: camera, web

I plan to create one website and two people can talk in my website.

in the web page, people can see each others, which each one installed web camera. just like skype embed in the web page. I have no idea how to implement it.
Another question is, is it possible to embed white board as well?

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Audio/Video communication over web you can use Web-RTC API from [OpenTok](https://tokbox.com/) , it can be embed easily into your website. For whiteboards you can search online which options best suits you. few examples are

https://highfive.com/blog/top-4-interactive-whiteboard-apps-remote-meetings/
https://webwhiteboard.com/